# i am getting this error saving the data in Sql Server "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.". below is my code:

Tags: c#, .net

```
string TJOBCODE1 = ddlJobCode.SelectedItem.Value;
string abc = ddlJobCode.SelectedItem.ToString();
string TJob_Name = abc.Substring(0, abc.IndexOf('['));
string TRo_Name = abc.Substring(abc.LastIndexOf('[') + 1);

TRo_Name = TRo_Name.Replace("]", "");
string TJOBCODE = TJOBCODE1;
SqlCommand fsql = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) AS REC FROM  [MTS_TV_RO_TC_FINAL] where JOB_CODE='" + TJOBCODE + "' AND AGENCY_CODE in( select agency_code FROM " + tmptvrlbktbl + ")", Global.con1);
SqlDataAdapter Fda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(fsql);
DataTable Fdt1 = new DataTable();
Fda1.Fill(Fdt1);
int DD = Convert.ToInt32(Fdt1.Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());

if (DD == 0)
{
    string INSQURY = " insert into  [MTS_TV_RO_TC_FINAL] ([DATE],[CAPTION_NAME],[IST],[DURATION],[AMOUNT],[CRID],[JOB_CODE],[AGENCY_CODE],[STATUS],[TBAND_IN],[TBAND_OUT],[DATE_FROM],[DATE_TO],[CREATE_DATE],[USER_NAME],[REMARKS],[Ro_Name],[Job_Name])   SELECT [DATE],[CAPTION],[IST],[DURATION],[AMOUNT],[CRID],'" + TJOBCODE + "',[Agency_code],[STAT],[TBAND_IN],[TBAND_OUT],'" + COMP_FROM + "','" + COMP_TO + "',GETDATE() AS DT,'" + Global.uname + "' ,[REMARKS],'" + TRo_Name + "','" + TJob_Name + "' FROM " + tmptvrlbktbl + " ORDER BY DATE";

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(INSQURY, Global.con1);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Alert.show1("Data Saved Successfully", this);
}
else
{
    Alert.show1("Data Already Saved", this);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question

Comment: Why did you remove all of the code?

Comment: What are the values of COMP_FROM and COMP_TO?

Comment: The duration of the work are the values , they are above inserted in the table 'tmptvrlbktbl'

Comment: We need to see the format of COMP_FROM AND COM_TO.  I take it these are strings?

Comment: no, they have been declared as  DateTime COMP_FROM, COMP_TO;

Comment: Agree with @JonathanWillcock. The problem might be with their format- check if they are dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: If you use a parametrised query instead of string concatenation you will not have the issue of trying to convert strings to other formats. Right now the datetimes are being converted to strings by the string concatenation in a format that's specific to the locale your code's running in and SQL can't handle that.

Comment: No, it is in same format as date i.e MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Try using parameterized query.

Comment: thanks @J.Steen, using parametrized query solved my issue. thanks @ Chetan Ranpariya too!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change insQury to

```
string INSQURY = " insert into  [MTS_TV_RO_TC_FINAL] ([DATE],[CAPTION_NAME],[IST],[DURATION],[AMOUNT],[CRID],[JOB_CODE],[AGENCY_CODE],[STATUS],[TBAND_IN],[TBAND_OUT],[DATE_FROM],[DATE_TO],[CREATE_DATE],[USER_NAME],[REMARKS],[Ro_Name],[Job_Name])   SELECT [DATE],[CAPTION],[IST],[DURATION],[AMOUNT],[CRID],'" + TJOBCODE + "',[Agency_code],[STAT],[TBAND_IN],[TBAND_OUT],COMP_FROM, COMP_TO,GETDATE() AS DT,'" + Global.uname + "' ,[REMARKS],'" + TRo_Name + "','" + TJob_Name + "' FROM " + tmptvrlbktbl + " ORDER BY DATE";
```

If COMP_FROM and COMP_TO are dates already you don't need to surround them with single quotation marks.

Comment: It is not showing any error but throwing back to the same page again, data is not getting saved.

Comment: OK so now the problem is different.  Are you sure that 'tmptvrlbktbl' contains data?  Could you please post the data it contains - one line will do, as an example!

Comment: It would also be useful to know the output of ExecuteNonQuery().  This returns the number of rows affected (in this case inserted).

Comment: Thanks! but i used parametrized query and solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

The code was perfectly fine, there was an issue with the excel sheet. i changed the query to parametrized and changed the excel sheet as well and it worked.